# aws deployment error ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotAuthorizedError: Operation Denied. Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy my python programme unto aws using  `eb create django-env`, but it has been producing this error

```
NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied
```

On further digging deep through `eb create --debug` it produced this error

```
ebcli.lib.aws.InvalidParameterValueError: Platform ARN is invalid: Not an IAM ARN: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.3.4 running Python 3.8.
```

when it got to `Select a load balancer type` section and I selected option 2 i.e. application

but when I selected `option 1 i.e. classic` for `Select a load balancer type section` it produced

```
ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotAuthorizedError: Operation Denied. Access Denied
```

This is the error message

```
    2021-08-01 09:38:36,597 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : File size: 78041269
    2021-08-01 09:38:36,612 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Inside get_storage_location api wrapper
    2021-08-01 09:38:36,612 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, create_storage_location) to region:us-west-2 with args:{}
    2021-08-01 09:38:38,811 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
    2021-08-01 09:38:38,811 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'S3Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-395403681453', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '2a9c9762-4a6d-46e0-9a28-c92a300b3a8c', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'date': 'Sun, 01 Aug 2021 08:38:39 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
    2021-08-01 09:38:38,811 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Creating new Botocore Client for s3
    2021-08-01 09:38:38,906 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Successfully created session for s3
    2021-08-01 09:38:38,906 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (s3, list_objects) to region: us-west-2 with args:{'Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-395403681453', 'Prefix': 'django-tutotrial/app-210801_093611.zip'}
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,130 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,130 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'CJTFFNJ9QBMJAQWW', 'HostId': 'rY/gGdjoVhTa3Z2JgGgQAtGlQnf9Gg/ksaJjQmEF3zgxt9n+ddNL82b7HngUg1If4j4M4R6c2iA=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'date': 'Sun,01 Aug 2021 08:38:43 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'IsTruncated': False, 'Marker': '', 'Name': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-395403681453', 'Prefix': 'django-tutotrial/app-210801_093611.zip', 'MaxKeys': 1000, 'EncodingType': 'url'}
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,130 (INFO) eb : Uploading archive to s3 location: django-tutotrial/app-210801_093611.zip
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,135 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\users\system1\django\firstproject
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,135 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.s3 : Upload Application Version. File size = 78041269
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,135 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.s3 : Doing multi-threaded upload. Parts Needed=15
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,140 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (s3, list_multipart_uploads) to region: us-west-2 withargs:{'Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-395403681453', 'Prefix': 'django-tutotrial/app-210801_093611.zip'}
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,635 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'Error': {'Code': 'AccessDenied', 'Message': 'Access Denied'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'CJT8SW62G2YGRV15', 'HostId': 'zBtbEFfyKXfyCev+TIb84iVzuvFoFa9KTgUQZ/CQR99QS0urPPu+oJjnO/sJbKLHLbsiSqwuOPk=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 403, 'date': 'Sun, 01 Aug 2021 08:38:41 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,640 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 403
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,640 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Received a 403
    2021-08-01 09:38:41,885 (INFO) eb : Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\operations\commonops.py", line 540, in create_app_
    version
        s3.get_object_info(bucket, key)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 90, in get_object_info
        __raise_if_bucket_is_empty(result)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 53, in __raise_if_bucket_is_empty
        raise NotFoundError('Object not found.')
    ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotFoundError: Object not found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\aws.py", line 212, in make_api_call
        response_data = operation(**operation_options)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 386, in _api_call
        return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
        raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListMultipartUploads operation: Access Denied

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\ebrun.py", line 62, in run_app
        app.run()
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\cement\core\foundation.py", line 797, in run
        return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\cement\core\controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
        return func()
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\cement\core\controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
        return func()
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\core\abstractcontroller.py", line 92, in default
        self.do_command()
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\controllers\create.py", line 281, in do_command
        createops.make_new_env(env_request,
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\operations\createops.py", line 75, in make_new_env
        commonops.create_app_version(env_request.app_name, process=process_app_version,
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\operations\commonops.py", line 548, in create_app_version
        s3.upload_application_version(bucket, key, file_path)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 149, in upload_application_version
        upload_workspace_version(bucket, key, file_path, 'Application')
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 144, in upload_workspace_version
        result = multithreaded_upload(bucket, key, file_path)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 178, in multithreaded_upload
        upload_id = _get_multipart_upload_id(bucket, key)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 311, in _get_multipart_upload_id
        response = _make_api_call('list_multipart_uploads',
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\s3.py", line 40, in _make_api_call
        return aws.make_api_call('s3', operation_name, **operation_options)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\aws.py", line 221, in make_api_call_handle_response_code(e.response, attempt, aggregated_error_message)
      File "c:\users\system1\django\venv\lib\site-packages\ebcli\lib\aws.py", line 289, in _handle_response_code
        raise NotAuthorizedError('Operation Denied. ' + message)
    ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotAuthorizedError: Operation Denied. Access Denied
```

what can be the reason for this. When I checked the user's account on aws I could see that an activity took place some few minutes earlier. durin the `eb create`  opration
This shows that the problem was from aws itself but some authorization was not in place.
I initially thought it ws a credential problem. on later checking the account i was linkng to i saw that user's aaccount last activity changed

1. Please how can I correct this error?
2. How can i locate a specific user's error log in aws?
3. is there anything on my ws account which i need to do?, i have already created the credential and the account shows some activities took place on it by the updating of lst activity time related to the user
4. Is there a certain configuration i need to do on my aws account?

Comment: Try looking at the [CloudTrail event history](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/home#/events) and the [CloudWatch logs](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home#logsV2:log-groups).

Comment: @Hcaertnit Thank you. I was able to get some error log. `"errorCode":"LimitExceededException",` , `"errorCode":"EntityAlreadyExistsException",`. I am still looking at what can I do get that over with

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I solved this by adding this policy to the user's list of policies: "AmazonS3FullAccess"

Answer (score 0):

In response to OP's question #2, you can run the create command with `--debugboto` to get more verbose error logs.

`eb create --debugboto`

I had the same error, the verbose logs indicated a permissions issue with S3.